# GridView.DataSource в DataTable или отделение данных от представления

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть дефолтный список людей.

```
  humans = new List<Human>
    {
        new Human{ Name="Вася", Sex = Sex.Male ,Item = Item.Чайная},
        new Human{ Name="ВаНЯ", Sex = Sex.Male ,Item = Item.Чайная}
    };
```

```
  public class Human
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Sex Sex { get; set; }
        public Item Item {get;set;}
    }
```

Список используется на всех вкладках утилиты отображая по Sex нужные имена(чекбоксы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполняю я ее так 
`dataGridView1.DataSource = humans;`

Юзер вводит нужное количество ложек на каждой нужной вкладке.
На выходе мне нужно получать файлы.txt.

Каждый файл соответствует вкладке.
Внутри будут строки: ( имя повторяется введенное количество раз)

---

чайная.txt

1. Вася
2. Вася
3. Аня

---

**Наконец Вопрос =)**

Нужно использовать несколько datagridview для каждой вкладки? И заполнять каждый dataGridView из humans .И потом каждую выгружать в имя_вкладки.txt.

*Я слышал, что отделение данных от представления хорошая практика.*

И понял что мои манипуляции в dataGridView , копирование, изменение Cells.Value итд не совсем верное решение.

Тогда я решил что мне надо работать с Datatable и просто добавлять в неё при переходе на новую вкладку новые строки, копируя уже существующие с item = чайная  меняя сам Item на столовую в новых, если таковых нет.

И к событию выбора вкладки Столовая

```
var result = humans.Where(x => x.Item == Item.Столовая)
dataGridView1.DataSource = humans;
```

Таким образом на каждой вкладке будут отображаться только чайные. либо столовые.Хотя данные все лежат в одной таблице.Кажется это удобно.

И мне будет легко копировать целые строки, или менять значения ячейки...

Но я не знаю как из GridView.DataSource в DataTable эти данные экспортировать.
Я пробовал `DataTable tbl = Gridview1.DataSource as DataTable;` Но получаю Null.

Работать с humans очевидно менее удобно.

Может сразу заполнять из humans DataTable а потом уже указывать ее к DataSource.(Как тогда сделать это?)

А может я вообще изобретаю велосипед.. Как лучше делать?

Comment: прочитал два раза, но к сожалению не совсем понял суть вашей проблемы, можно еще раз, но одним предложением?

Comment: Данные GridView.DataSource = people; экспортировать в DataTable?

Comment: Но в целом вопрос конечно, о том, каким образом лучше организовать алгоритм работы для приложения с подобными нуждами

Comment: Вы используете `List`, а не `DataTable`.

Comment: Справедливо ) Тогда как convert this list object to a DataTable

Comment: Зачем? У вас есть `List` - вот с ним и работайте. Или откажитесь от списка полностью, если больше нравится `DataTable`.

Comment: `Human` - это единственное число. Это сбивает с толку, когда вы говорите про коллекцию. Коллекции обычно зовут во множественном: `humans`. Или `humanList`, `humanCollection`, `humanDataTable`. И вообще отредактируйте своё сообщение: у вас там `people` упоминается.

Comment: Заполнять List именами и другими его элементами , удобнее мне кажется чем заполнять Datatable. Только по этому появилась подобная нужда. Из List заполнить уже Datatable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока помогло это

```
public class ListtoDataTableConverter

        {

            public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)

            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
                PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
                }
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    var values = new object[Props.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                    {
                        values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
                }
                return dataTable;
            }

        }
```

```
ListtoDataTableConverter converter = new ListtoDataTableConverter();

       DataTable dt = converter.ToDataTable(humans);
```

Comment: А для чего вам вообще DataTable понадобился?